# gulp-eslint: TypeError: (0 , _eslint2.default) is not a function

Tags: gulp, eslint, babeljs, gulp-eslint

Trying to run eslint with gulp and getting this error. What have I missed? Here's my `gulpfile.bable.js` file.

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import eslint from 'eslint';

const jsFiles = ['*.js', 'src/**/*.js'];

gulp.task('lint', () => {
  gulp.src(jsFiles)
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Here's the full error:

```
C:\Users\promer\projects\library>gulp lint
[14:50:35] Requiring external module babel-register
[14:50:35] Using gulpfile ~\projects\library\gulpfile.babel.js
[14:50:35] Starting 'lint'...
[14:50:35] 'lint' errored after 10 ms
[14:50:35] TypeError: (0 , _eslint2.default) is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:/Users/promer/projects/library/gulpfile.babel.js:8:11)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\promer\projects\library\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Users\promer\projects\library\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Users\promer\projects\library\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Users\promer\projects\library\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\promer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a simple mistake. I almost deleted the question, but I figured someone else might make the same mistake I did. While I have gulp-eslint installed I was actually loading regular eslint into my gulp file. The fix is to change this line

```
import eslint from 'eslint'
```

to

```
import eslint from 'gulp-eslint'
```